# TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer в datetime.date

Tags: python, datetime, type-error

У меня есть код на python:

```py
new_date = datetime.date(year=2000, month=month, day=data)
```

но я получаю ошибку

```
new_date = datetime.date(year=int(2000),
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

что я делаю не так?

Comment: А чему равны переменные `month` и `data`? Ошибка не всегда чётко указывается в нужном месте. К тому же у вас код явно отличается тот, который вы предоставили и тот, который в ошибке.

Comment: Спасибо, я посмотрел типы переменных и понял что data типа str, сделал int(data) и это помогло